# Delphi alternative to php unpack

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, unpack

Ia there any delphi function similar to php unpack ?

https://www.php.net/unpack

Example of calling :
unpack (" V ", $buff);

Comment: No.  But why do you need it? In your example, just use `Move()` to copy the binary data into a `Cardinal`/`DWord` array.

Comment: There is something similar when you use WriteComponent, which can serialize a component hierarchy to a binary or textual representation. With TReader/TWriter you can also write values of different types to a steam easily. This is not 1:1 compatible with pack/unpack, but I can imagine that it would be fairly easy to write a class that implements reading pack-generated streams.